# how can i make a mysql batch update stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, batch-processing

So I wanted to create a stored procedure to update a batch of rows. I usually do this with looping the stored procedure in my code behind but this has some performance setback. My problem is how to pass the parameters to the query since the total number of rows to be changed varies.

This is my single row update stored procedure, how can I convert it to process more than 1 rows and how can I pass those rows as parameters?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EditProductType;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE EditProductType(
  IN productTypeId INT,
  IN NAME VARCHAR(100),
  IN details VARCHAR(1000)
)
BEGIN

UPDATE product_types pt
SET pt.name = NAME,
    pt.details = details
WHERE pt.productTypeId = productTypeId;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I do not see, why you need a SP for this. And I do not know, why you call that batch. Each client can do that without batch functionality

Comment: Can you make this question into an [mre], and add some (sample) input

Comment: im trying to mimic the excel where you modify several rows then hit the save all button and all modified rows will be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not practical to `UPDATE` more than one row at a time unless

- The `WHERE` clause references multiple rows (without any variation)

OR

- You have a table with the changes and you use a multi-table `UPDATE` that `JOINs` your table and that table.

**IODKU**

I consider this to be an ugly solution, but I will present it anyway.

```
INSERT INTO t (id,b,c)
    VALUES
    (10,'doohickie',3),
    (22,'whatchamacallit',44),
    (98,'doodad',55),
    (34,'thingamabob',56)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    b = VALUES(b),
    c = VALUES(c) ;
```

Assumptions:

- `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` (or a `UNIQUE` key).
- You have specified rows that already exist; that way, the `INSERT` half of IODKU won't be used, just the `UPDATE` half.

If you already have `id,b,c` in a table `temp`, this would work (probably better):

```
INSERT INTO t (id,b,c)
    SELECT id,b,c  FROM temp
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    b = VALUES(b),
    c = VALUES(c) ;
```